# java 101, how do I count the number of arguments passed into main?

Tags: java, count, program-entry-point, args

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int count = 0;
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
                count++;

        }

    }
```

is there some way of doing something like

int count = args.length()? or args.size()?

Comment: As everyone else has said, args.length is better. This is because the method of counting, while 100% valid, takes `n` loops, where `n` is the length of the array, whereas accessing args.length takes `1` loop, making it far faster. You can't change the `length` field, but you can still access it (we call this "final").

Comment: So many duplicate answers. Do we really need 6 answers for using array's `length` field?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be:

```
int count = args.length;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was getting errors using args.length() with the brackets. I didn't see any reason why I should be able to do that. Silly mistake, thanks.

Comment: Arrays are special in Java, and carry `length` as a member field rather than a method call, so no parentheses. When using the [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework), such as `ArrayList`, you would be calling the [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#size()) method, and parentheses are required. Now that I think about it, it would be worth filing a feature-request to ask that a `size()` method be added to arrays, as syntactic sugar, just for the sake of consistency and convenience.

Answer (score 4):

> is there some way of doing something like
>
> int count = args.length()? or args.size()?

Yes, `args.length`.

There is nothing special about `args`; it is a regular array of `String` objects and may be treated as such.

Answer (score 2):

All arrays have a "field" called `length`

```
int count = args.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"args" is just an array, so you can use it's length property.

Like this:

```
System.out.println(args.length);
```

and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use
 `int length=args.length`

args is simply an array and you can use it's length property.